# Using Namespaces instead of Nested Classes?

Tags: c#

This is a problem I have been having for awhile now and can't seem to ever find an answer for it so I was hoping I could find it here.

```cs
// Qualifier.cs
namespace CP {
    public partial class Rate {
        public partial class Detail {
            public partial class Adjustment {
                public partial class Qualifier {
                    private readonly double percent;
                    public Qualifier(XElement element) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Rate.cs
namespace CP {
    public partial class Rate {
        public Detail detail; 
    }
}

// Detail.cs
namespace CP {
    public partial class Rate {
        public partial class Detail {
            public Adjustment adjustment;
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at this code example, you can see there's a lot of nesting going on here and it bothers me because I feel like this isn't the proper or most efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

I do it like this because I want the ability to get an instance of a Rate (for example) and be able to do things like, `rate.detail.adjustment.qualifier.percent`. This gives me a complete object from the database with all its relationships.

At first I thought I'd be able to do this in the Namespace, something like `CP.Rate.Detail.Adjustment`, but because all these classes exist in the namespace, this obviously isn't possible.

So they question is, is this a good practice? If it's not, can you lead me in the right direction to correct this issue.

Edit:

I'm doing it for organizational purposes, describing objects and their relationships through name spacing. So if I wanted to get the details of a rate. The call would be `Rate.Detail.GetDetail()`. And if I had another detail, say in Order, it would be `Order.Detail.GetDetail()`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: From your description, it's not clear to me why you have your classes nested like this, nor can I understand how you envision the use of namespaces as a solution. Can you show us some example code that makes use of this nesting? If we can't understand what you're actually trying to accomplish, it's hard to suggest an alternative, but typically, one level of nested classes is generally inadvisable. Four levels is bonkers.

Comment: @JLRishe Sorry about that. I added some explanation in an edit. You're right, it is bonkers. That's why I'm here :) haha

Comment: It seems like rather than nested classes, you need to look into [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). These allow you to store references to other objects, and access properties via the dot syntax.

Comment: @mason This is allowing me to access properties via the dot syntax already. Please see the edit, maybe it will help explain it better.

Comment: @KristoferDoman Your updated code still doesn't give any indication of why the classes would need to be nested. As far as I can tell, there is no need for them to be nested, nor is there a need for them to be `partial` either. Just make them separate, un-nested classes in separate .cs files and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces are typically used at a very high level, to help with things like when two completely different libraries end up exposing classes with the same name.

What it seems you're trying to accomplish with nested classes is usually better accomplished with properties. The `Rate` class would have a `Detail` property. If the *shape* of `Rate`'s `Detail` and `Order`'s `Detail` is the same, you'd use a single, non-nested `Detail` class to represent both. If it's different, you'd use different class names (`RateDetail` vs `OrderDetail`).

Rather than referencing your data by its class structure, reference it by the object structure. This can be done, for example, by having a singleton `CP` instance that gets instantiated with all the values you'd expect, so you can say something like `CP.Instance.Rate.Detail.Adjustment` (even though Detail's class might be `RateDetail` it's accessed via a property that's just named `Detail`).

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking the time to help. I will try to look into this approach as it seems it might be what I'm looking for. I do have properties in each class as well, as you can see in my last edit. I apologize for not including that from the start.